# Bash Chunk Loop Index Issue

Tags: bash, loops

I wish to iterate over a bash array in increments of 4. It works on the first iteration but on the second iteration, element position 3 gets mapped into element position 7.

Any ideas / pointers would be greatly appreciated?

Here is the code -

```
#!/bin/bash 
# Run as - /tmp/dns.sh qa aqa api

envType=$1      
clusterType=$2   
projectName=$3   

declare -a dnsAry

if [[ "${envType}" =~ "ci" ]]; then

    dnsAry+=("dev.example.com")
    dnsAry+=("${envType}-${projectName}")
    dnsAry+=("${clusterType}-${projectName}")
    dnsAry+=("${envType}-${projectName}-app-and-web-dns")
fi

if [[ "${envType}" =~ "qa" ]]; then

    dnsAry+=("dev.example.com")
    dnsAry+=("${envType}-${projectName}")
    dnsAry+=("${clusterType}-${projectName}")
    dnsAry+=("${envType}-${projectName}-app-dns")

    dnsAry+=("qa.example.com")
    dnsAry+=("${envType}-${projectName}")
    dnsAry+=("${clusterType}-${projectName}")
    dnsAry+=("${envType}-${projectName}-web-dns")
fi

echo -e "Array size : ${#dnsAry[@]}"
echo -e "Array content : ${dnsAry[@]}"

for (( j = 0; j < "${#dnsAry[@]}"; j+=4 )) do
    echo -e "Loop content $(( $j )) : ${dnsAry[${j}]}"  
    echo -e "Loop content $(( $j + 1)) : ${dnsAry[${j+1}]}" 
    echo -e "Loop content $(( $j + 2)) : ${dnsAry[${j+2}]}" 
    echo -e "Loop content $(( $j + 3)) : ${dnsAry[${j+3}]}" 
done
```

And the output -

```
/tmp/dns.sh qa aqa hapi

Array size : 8
Array content : dev.example.com qa-hapi aqa-hapi qa-hapi-app-dns qa.example.com qa-hapi aqa-hapi qa-hapi-web-dns
Loop content 0 : dev.example.com
Loop content 1 : qa-hapi
Loop content 2 : aqa-hapi
Loop content 3 : qa-hapi-app-dns
Loop content 4 : qa.example.com
Loop content 5 : qa-hapi
Loop content 6 : aqa-hapi
Loop content 7 : qa-hapi-app-dns
```

The expected output should be - note element 7.

```
/tmp/dns.sh qa aqa hapi

Array size : 8
Array content : dev.example.com qa-hapi aqa-hapi qa-hapi-app-dns qa.example.com qa-hapi aqa-hapi qa-hapi-web-dns
Loop content 0 : dev.example.com
Loop content 1 : qa-hapi
Loop content 2 : aqa-hapi
Loop content 3 : qa-hapi-app-dns
Loop content 4 : qa.example.com
Loop content 5 : qa-hapi
Loop content 6 : aqa-hapi
Loop content 7 : qa-hapi-web-dns
```

Comment: It seems perfectly fine to me. What was the output you expected?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it obvious? The way you access the array indices are *wrong*! The syntax `{var + 1}` is *not* a proper syntax for arithmetic increment in `bash`, you need to have had `((var + 1))`

```
for (( j = 0; j < "${#dnsAry[@]}"; j+=4 )) do
    echo -e "Loop content $(( $j )) : ${dnsAry[${j}]}"
    echo -e "Loop content $(( $j + 1)) : ${dnsAry[$((j+1))]}"
    echo -e "Loop content $(( $j + 2)) : ${dnsAry[$((j+2))]}"
    echo -e "Loop content $(( $j + 3)) : ${dnsAry[$((j+3))]}"
done
```

In your second iteration, when the control executes `${j + 1}`, the behavior results in a parameter expression syntax `${PARAMETER+WORD}` which means the resulting string will contain value of `WORD` if `PARAMETER` is set, i.e.  the alternate value will be used if the parameter is set.

So in the 2<sup>nd</sup> iteration, since the value of `j` is 4 now the expasions `${j + 1}`, `${j + 2}` and `${j + 3}` are set to values `1`, `2` and `3` and the values corresponding to those indices are printed.

See the example code below,

```
# foo="" 
foo="something"

if [[ ${foo+isset} = isset ]]; then
  echo "foo is set..."
else
  echo "foo is not set..."
fi
```

---

Or more simply just avoid introducing a scope of running parameter expansion for this and just use `${dnsAry[j+1]}` without the `${..}` introduced for the indices.